# Find previous character preceding in vim

Tags: vim

To find the next character in vim I can do:

`f` `(` # to find the next `(`

How would I do the same to find the previous `(` or charater (without using the `%` )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the previous `(` (in the same line) by pressing `F(`
similarly, you may want to know `t`, `T`,`,`, `;`

Do `:h F`, `T....` to see details.

Answer (score 1):

Note that although `F(` does what you ask for, you might be more interested in `[(`, which moves back to the most recent unmatched paren.  In other words, in the string `( foo ( bar ) baz )`, the cursor would move from the `r` to the 2nd paren, and from the `z` to the first.

Comment: thanks for this. What is the difference between doing `%` and `[` then? Or even `/(` (find)

Comment: `[` is more general. You can do things like `[{` and `[z` and `[[`, which are all very handy.  `:help [` for details

Comment: I actually had forgotten that `%` has similar functionality; I tend to only use it when I'm on the matching brace.

Answer (score 1):

If, rather than simply going to the paren, you're interested in operating on the *contents* inside the `()` in some way, you could use Vim "text objects" -- `i(` and `a(` refer to the contents "in" and "around" the parentheses. These can be used with any Vim verb, for instance:

`ci(` change in parens

`da(` delete around parens

Likewise there are also `i[`/`a[` and `it`/`at` for brackets and "tags," (like HTML tags) respectively, and [many others](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/) as well.

Finally, if you're interested in merely changing the parens to some other kind of delimiter, or in getting rid of them, then take a look at the [Vim Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.